# how to add css links in others pages Without distortion?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view for showing my products in it I've used `rPage` plugin for responsive pagination.but i have a problem with it.when I add bootstrap in top of page. all of element are being mess but `rPage` has good style.and vice versa when I remove bootstrap link `rpage` plugin is being mess. I add two images for better understanding.

these are css links in _AdminLayout.

```
   <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- chartist CSS -->
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist-init.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/chartist-plugin-tooltip-master/dist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/css-chart/css-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--This page css - Morris CSS -->
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/c3-master/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Vector CSS -->
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/assets/plugins/vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- You can change the theme colors from here -->
    <link href="~/content/materialpro/css/colors/blue.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently rPage is for Bootstrap 3. It's not compatible with Bootstrap 4, and kind of obsolete since Bootstrap 4 has the same functionality's and rPage.